# A column in MUI Datatable do not hide or show based on a state true or false condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mui-datatable

I'm trying to display or hide a column in an MUI datable based on a condition of a state.
I put ane example here which works
[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-brattain-cbkho?file=/src/App.js:1522-1575)

In this example, if you tweak line 14 between true and false, you will see a column is displayed or hide. Distance column.

This same behavior I'm trying to reach in my code but it does not work and I don't know why:
[Link to code](https://pastebin.com/t3XrzSGE)

I added a link as I have no idea what wrong but I tried the as same way I did in CodeSandBox:

The data in codeSandbox is a representation similar to what is here an OBJ containing two key/values

```
   {
         lat: 40.7110316
​
         lng: -74.0013216
    }
```

My data and state and function isDisplay()

```
    const [usingLocation, setLocation] = useState(null);
    
    const isDisplay = () => {
    if (usingLocation !== null) return true;
    else return false;
  };
```

My columns

```
const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      'Id',
      {
        name: 'Distance',
        options: {
          display: isDisplay(),
          filter: false,
          customBodyRender: value => {
            return !value ? 'N/A' : `${value} ${DISTANCE_MEASURE}`;
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    [sites, site],
  );
```

In my situation, the Distance column never shows even though the usingLocation is true.

I really don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `display: isDisplay()` in the memoized `columns` variable. But `isDisplay` is **not** declared in the dependency array, only `site` and `sites` are. This causes to `column` not to re-render when `isDisplay`'s return value changes.

So it should be:

```js
const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      'Id',
      {
        name: 'Distance',
        options: {
          display: isDisplay(),
          filter: false,
          customBodyRender: value => {
            return !value ? 'N/A' : `${value} ${DISTANCE_MEASURE}`;
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    [sites, site, isDisplay],
  );
```

Though, personally, I don't see a reason to memoize `columns`.

Comment: I memorized because in my situation when I was selecting and saving a row to DB the table was re-rendering and no saving data. Using memo I was able to save and force to have the data in place. Unfortunately I didn't find another solution to avoid that issue in this table.